# Desktop Shortcut Key takes too much time to open

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

I just found out that you can set a key combination to open a particular shortcut on your desktop. However, when I do this, it takes four to five seconds to open, consistently. How do I make this delay go away and make the shortcut open instantly?

For anyone wondering, the way to set the key combination is to right click the shortcut, select properties, go to the shortcut tab and set the Shortcut key property by selecting the field and pressing a key.

It seems you can only use ctrl+alt+key to open shortcuts, but I don't find that to be a problem.

Comment: Does the program open slower than **not** using the shortcut key?

Comment: Yes, if I click the shortcut it will open faster. Also, I'm not using it to open a program, I'm using it to open a folder.

Comment: Not that it is particularly relevant, but opening a folder is running a program (explorer)

Comment: Right, but I thought it might exclude the possibility that the delay was caused by the program itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press the key combination, explorer will query all opened windows to check if one of them has this shortcut associated (so it can give the focus to this window)
So, if you have a frozen window/program, explorer will wait for an answer until the ~4 second timeout is reached, and then give up.

It's explained by Raymond on this blog:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120502-00/?p=7723

Comment: Thank you, this answers the question nicely! Now I just need to figure out which open window causes this haha!

Answer (score 0):

Disabling application pre-launch in SysMain/Superfetch has solved the problem for me. There's no need to disable SysMain entirely.

Open an elevated Powershell window and use the following command:

```
Disable-MMAgent -ApplicationPreLaunch
```

Then, restart your computer. Desktop shortcut keys shouldn't be sluggish anymore.